# Magento advance search giving error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, advanced-search

i have added the following code in my cms home page

```
{{block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

it shows the form on home page well but whenever i search for any thing it givs me the following error:

> Whoops, our bad...
>   The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

I also tried this in page template but the same error appears

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: this worked fine for me [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29195/how-to-show-advanced-search-in-custom-phtml)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change form action URL (catalogsearch\advanced\form.phtml) like this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result'); ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">
```